# Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Anyone can help to solve this problem...?
I made a code for RNN study but there was the error when I input outputs line..

```
X_one_hot = tf.one_hot(X, num_classes) # one_hot: 1 -> 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units = rnn_hidden_size, state_is_tuple = True)
initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_one_hot, initial_state = initial_state, dtype = tf.float32)
```

But I got this issue

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

File "C:\Users\82108\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "C:\Users\82108\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\82108\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
```

Comment: Does this happen when you run the model for the first time? If this is not the case, you need to clear you computational graph by using 'tf.reset_default_graph()'. By the way,  `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` must have a Tensor of shape  `[batch_size, max_time, ...]`. Use a placeholder `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, None, N))`, which is then fed into the rnn like `outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x)`.

Comment: Thanks, my friend. it's really working well, when I restart kernel or using your code.
Yes, I used a tf.placeholder, but didn't know about max_time arg. thanks for your help again.